# Format array to append text in TextField in Tabular Format

Tags: java, javafx, string.format

I am storing a multiple strings  in a List Array then  I output them to a textArea in my JavaFX scene. Here is what What I want my output to look like. notice how evenly my string spaced regardless of the number of characters.

```
acdd abc  abcd  abcd 
ab   abcd abcdf abcd
```

To output my List I put it through a for loop and append "\n" to each line.

```
for (String line : lines) {
      sb.append(line).append("\n");
     }
```

Now If I print the newStr via println it looks perfect.

```
System.out.println(listStringJoin(newStr));
acdd abc  abcd  abcd 
ab   abcd abcdf abcd
```

However, my issue is when I add or append the newStr to the textArea in my JavaFX scene.                    `myTextArea.appendText(listStringJoin(newStr));`

The result, un-spaced output.

```
acdd  abc  abcd abcd 
ab   abcd abcdf  abcd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first get the largest element in array and then add spaces to other smaller elements.

Here's a method to generate even tabular format from a String Array:

```
public static String[] generateTable(ArrayList<String> lines){
// A list to store every single element individually
ArrayList<String> sl = new ArrayList<>();
int length = lines.get(0).split(" ").length; // Number of individual
                                            // elements

// Create an array of every element individually
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] sp = line.split(" ");
    for (String semiChars : sp)
        sl.add(semiChars);
}

// This controls iteration
int j = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < sl.size() / lines.size(); i++) {
    int maxLength = 0; // Max length of character within that set
    String fixStr = ""; // String with fixed spaces

    // Determine maximum length from set
    // Compares the element lengths in multiples. Something like:
    // (element i, element i+length, element i+length+length.....)
    while (j < sl.size()) {
        fixStr = sl.get(i + j - 1);
        if (maxLength < sl.get(i + j - 1).length())
            maxLength = sl.get(i + j - 1).length();
        j += length;
    }

    j = 1; // Ready for another loop
    // Add spaces to match max length in set
    while (j < sl.size()) {
        fixStr = "";
        // Gets elements in multiples (same as above loop)
        if (sl.get(i + j - 1).length() < maxLength) {
            fixStr = sl.get(i + j - 1);
            while (fixStr.length() < maxLength)
                fixStr += " ";
            sl.set(i + j - 1, fixStr);
        }
        j += length;
    }

    j = 1; // Ready for another loop
}

// Time to create final array that is returned

String semiElement = ""; // Stores elements as sets of lines
String[] sortedArray = new String[lines.size()]; // The final Array

// Form expression and add it to final Array
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    j = 0;
    while (j < length) {
        // Add as many spaces as you want between elements here
        semiElement += (sl.get((i * length) + j) + "   ");
        j++;
    }
    sortedArray[i] = semiElement;
    semiElement = "";
}

return sortedArray;
}
```

Input (a String Array):

```
{ "line1 11111 asd ghdfigh asdi bbb 222",
  "line2 2 asdasf gg weew bbb 666",
  "line3 22222asdas as rte fhdfh ger 777",
  "line4 asdsa 23 as wete f 8888888",
  "line5 166 azzfffffffff gjj tyi btb 99000" };
```

Output:

```
line1   11111        asd            ghdfigh   asdi    bbb   222       
line2   2            asdasf         gg        weew    bbb   666       
line3   22222asdas   as             rte       fhdfh   ger   777       
line4   asdsa        23             as        wete    f     8888888   
line5   166          azzfffffffff   gjj       tyi     btb   99000
```

Comment: But the formate will look odd. the 2 characters cell will have the same length as 25 characters cell.

Comment: I'll change the code to fix that. Do both the lines always have same number of words/elements?

Comment: Sometimes. for example if I am collecting names as "Name: First and Last name" First and Last name will vary in length, but the word Name: itself will remain the same size across the lines.

Comment: Alright, edited my code. Now it will always generate even tabular formatted String Array.

Comment: Thanks so much!! But can you make a modification to the code so it can  work with ArrayList<> instead of string public static String[] generateTable(List<String> lines){. I tried modifying the code but I am having an issue with .length.

Comment: Edited code to use ArrayList. But it will accept only String generic types. Convert data types if necessary before passing as parameter. Also, the `length` equivalent of ArrayLists is `size()`. Also check out my answer's edit history. It has code for how to use my answer with String array, ArrayList and List.